# Is anyone try to deploy same smart contract on different Chain network like binance smart chain, polygon matic and avalanche?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, cross-chain

The scenario is, I want to deploy the same smart contract in binance smart chain to polygon matic and avalanche. Or I want to deploy same contract on different chain network like bsc, matic and avax. The smart contract is the same, and What about the price of the token? Is it sychronized price? or depends on the market of different network? Like applying cross-chain of token, how token cross-chain works?

Comment: Hi I have the same question, have you found the response ?

Comment: none sir at all